# Is this present perfect statement from Novak Djokovic gramatically correct?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

In his recent interview with BBC, Novak Djokovic says ([link to the interview starting at 3:51](https://youtu.be/rNaIMC4XMhc?t=231)):

> You know, no one in the whole process, during the Australian saga, **has asked me** on my stance or my opinion on vaccination.

I went through [this great article on perfect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it/) and also the one on [tenses](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/tense/info), but still have some doubts - is the above usage of present perfect from Novak correct?

Following the Reichenbach model, the Reference Time here is in the past (during the Australian saga) and the Event Time seems to me to be the same. As such, should the past simple be used instead?

Comment: Are you asking about 'no one ... has asked me', which is OK, or 'asked me **on** my stance', which is not?

Comment: I would say that the clear implication is that he thinks of the "Australian saga" as still ongoing. With the disclaimer that off-the-cuff speech is often imprecise, all the more so in the field of sports, and that he might be conflating multiple time frames (e.g.: "during the Australian saga," *if* he regards it as concluded, can be understood as a parenthetical aside with some omitted and assumed language like "in the whole process, or even during the Australian saga, has..."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey about 'no one ... has asked me' - I didn't even notice the preposition mistake. It should have been "asked me about my stance", shouldn't it?

Comment: @InStitches I think "has asked me" is fine.  He's basically talking about what has happened *up to this point*, so the present perfect is a natural choice.